# Which ports used by other programs?

Tags: networking, cmd, port

**i want to know which ports of my computer is used by some other applications...**

how could i know this ?

something like this :

```
Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Comment: I use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html Currports for this very thing, when on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
netstat -b
```

This returns the port and the programm which uses it. E.g.:

```
Aktive Verbindungen

  Proto  Lokale Adresse         Remoteadresse          Status
  TCP    192.168.x.y:2281       stackoverflow:http     HERGESTELLT
 [firefox.exe]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

NETSTAT -p tcp -ano

you can also use

NetConnectManager tool to monitor TCP/IP  as well as UDB ports.